# Pandas table viewing help in vscode Mac

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, visual-studio-code

I do the usual import pandas as pd and then add a file path for pandas to read. eg:

```
filename = 'vaccination_tweets.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename)

df
```

however, when I run this, nothing shows up. How can I see the table with all the columns in vscode version 1.52.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the print function on your df variable.
print(df)

Perhaps you are used to doing this in Jupyter Notebooks where you can simply call df and it will display the table.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try `print(df)` to print the actual df?